# How to make Eclipse work with the snippet macro in maven doxia files?

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse, doxia

I want to use the snippet macro in my maven site documentation in order to allow for testing of my examples code snippets with JUnit. But I don't want Eclipse to show the red "there is a build error" marker for all of my projects (which it does since m2eclipse does not recognize the snippet macro). I do want maven dependency management to be enabled for the projects in Eclipse, so disabling the maven integration completely is not an option. Moving to a different IDE is not an option either since I cannot force all of my coworkers to switch from Eclipse as well.

I would like a solution to either:

- Make the Doxia integration in (m2)Eclipse recognize or ignore the snippet macro
- Make Eclipse ignore errors in apt files altogether

Comment: As of today, the snippet macro seems to work for me if applied correctly (Eclipse >= Mars, Doxia 1.0.0.201301041016). However, I need to specify the _absolute_ path to a file, because `${basedir}` is not evaluated correctly as specified in [the docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-snippet-macro.html). The need to use `%{snippet|file=C:/my-path/..../snippet.adoc}` makes this pretty useless though, because any collaboration is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling the Doxia support is one solution.

Under the Help menu, click "Install new software", then "Already installed".
Select the "Maven Doxia" bundle and click "Uninstall...".

Comment: If anyone can find a solution that would enable me to keep using the Doxia support that would be better, since I quite liked to be able to preview the document right there in Eclipse.